# Почему в B деревьях минимальное количество ключей t-1

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, структуры-данных, data-structures

Прямое выражение из википедии: "Корень содержит от 1 до 2t-1 ключей. Любой другой узел содержит от t-1 до 2t-1 ключей."
Я нигде не могу найти примеры, где понятно будет объяснено что за параметр t. Как я понял t - это максимальное число указателей на дочерние узлы, а между указателями находятся ключи. Ключей всегда на 1 меньше, чем указателей. Так почему в узле минимальное количество - t-1, а не просто 1, ведь в любом узле любого b-tree теоретически же может быть всего 1 ключ? Помогите разобраться, а то сам не понимаю, в структурах данных еще начинающий.

Comment: Приведите источник

Comment: Если бы мог быть 1 - дерево было бы вырожденным, и смысла в нем не было бы никакого...

Comment: Очевидно, что `t` это количество элементов, которые мы помещаем в новый узел, который образуется при расщеплении переполняемого узла при добавлении нового элемента в дерево. (просто попробуйте написать сами алгоритмы работы с B-деревьями и все станет понятно)